# How to open popup window outside screen coordinates in Javascript

Tags: javascript, popup, window

I have multiple monitors in my system. 
My application is opened on the first monitor. When the user clicks an icon I would like to open popup window on the second monitor.

e.g.
`window.open(...."left=1500,top=400"...)`

it won't work, it always open my window in the first monitor - in the parent monitor.

Any ideas?
Thanks
Gilgol.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not open the window with the default co-ordinates, and then within the page that you're opening, set the co-ordinates of the window to the second monitor?

```
window.onload = function()
{
    self.moveTo(1500, 400);
};
```